# rails select_tag cannot be named "express"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I found an issue with my rails application.

When I name a select_tag "express", and use `options_from_collection_for_select` function to append options. nothing would be appended.

```
<%= select_tag "express", options_from_collection_for_select(@expresses, "id", "name"), class: "form-control" %>
```

When I do this, it works fine

```
<%= select_tag "expres", options_from_collection_for_select(@expresses, "id", "name"), class: "form-control" %>
```

After I create a new sample app, `express` actually works. How can I debug this issue?

UPDATE:

When I place this select_tag twice, the 2nd one render correctly.

Comment: Do any errors appear in the console log? I'm guessing you're using "rails s" to start up the server.

Comment: @Iceman, Yes I am using "rails s". But I don't see any error log on the console.

Comment: What is your model name? Is it `Express` or `Expres`?

Comment: @Pavan, my model name is Express. Good insight! When I change “@expresses” to another data source, it works correctly.

Comment: @Pavan, but I on my sample app, I try to named my select_tag as my Model. It works.

Comment: @etlds Glad it worked! Fell free to post it as an answer.